# How to remove duplicate legends in plotly python when appending traces in a loop?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a script where I'm trying to plot the means of various dataframes in a loop, but they should share the same legend. Can anyone help me on how to remove the duplicates in this case?

```
column = 1
rowww = 1
fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=3)

i = 0
for disco in discos:

    df1 = meanOfModels(discosList[disco])
    df2 = meanOfModels(discosList[disco])

    print(rowww, column)


    fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=df1.index,
                            y=df1.mean(axis=1),
                            line=dict(color='blue'),
                            name='df1',
                            legendgroup='df1'),
                 row=rowww,
                 col=column)
    fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2.index,
                            y=df2.mean(axis=1),
                            line=dict(color='red'),
                            name='df2',
                            legendgroup='df2'),
                 row=rowww,
                 col=column)

    column += 1
    if column % 4 == 0:
       rowww += 1
       column = 1


fig.layout.update(title='Average Decrease in Ampacity (%)', showlegend=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Duplicate legend items can be handled by using a counter in the loop process to enable them only the first time. `name='df1' if i == 0 else ''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution from an other thread, pasting it here.

Keeping the rest of the code same, but adding this bit before `fig.show()` makes the duplicate legends disappear.

```
names = set()
fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace:
        trace.update(showlegend=False)
        if (trace.name in names) else names.add(trace.name))
```